# Python: How do you import a function that is in a different directory?

Tags: python, import

The way im currently importing functions is by putting .py files into the "site-packages" directory then calling them using the following command in IDLE:

```
from myfile import *
```

I cannot find the "site-packages" directory inside of python3.2 in ubuntu so I need another way to import. thanks.

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages` or `site-packages`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your [PYTHONPATH](http://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/path.html) to include the other directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to PYTHONPATH issues. I would recommend using virtual envs and pip as standard when working with packages you've imported or obatined externally.

Some great notes here: https://python-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

If you wnat to import your own code. I'd set your PYTHONPATH (in the case below the dev_folder) to a root development directory and follow this structure...

```
dev_folder \
    - project_name \
        - main_script.py
        - helper.py
        - libary1 \
            - __init__.py
            - lib1.py
        - libary2 \
            - __init__.py
            - lib2.py
```

You'd obviously come up with better names for the library folders/packages :-)

Hope this helps.